# Call make from inside LLDB

Tags: debugging, lldb

I noticed that it is possible to call Gnu Make from gdb’s prompt, but it does not work with lldb.

Is there a way to call to call make from lldb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lldb has a `platform shell` command that you can use to run any single shell command.  You could certainly use that to call make.

lldb also has a Python interpreter (`script`) and Python has pretty robust support for interacting with the system.  So you can use that for fancier interactions.

It doesn't have support for any particular build system, however.